# Is it possible to activate Power BI in On Premise Data Gateway?

Tags: azure, microsoft-powerbi

I have installed an On-premises data gateway. I use it for powerautomate-tasks.
Now I want to access with Power BI to a database in our company.

But the On-premises data gateway says "Power BI - Not available". Do I have to activate this? How can this be achieved?

[image]